# How can C-SCAN (elevator) algorithm cause starvation?

Tags: algorithm, io, operating-system, scheduling, disk

I'm reading [Silberschatz's OS book](http://books.google.com/?isbn=9780470398791). In section 16.8.1 it says:

> The fundamental problem with the elevator algorithm is that I/O
>   operations cocentrated in a specific region of the disk can result in
>   starvation of requests that need to occur in other regions of the
>   disk.

The C-SCAN algorithm, processes all sectors in order, as illustrated on [this web page](http://www.cs.odu.edu/~cs471w/spring11/lectures/MassStorage.htm).
I don't understand how this could cause some requests to wait indefinitely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at Silberschatz's *Operating System Concepts* 7th edition you'll find that n exercise 7.5's answer he says starvation "the situation whereby a process must wait beyond a reasonable period of time—perhaps indefinitely—before receiving a requested resource." so SCAN and C-SCAN may spend an awful long time near one hot region of the disk before getting back to a starving area somewhere else. The starvation doesn't have to be a permanent denial of service.

Answer (score 1):

It could be made to wait indefinitely if the same sector were requested over and over. The disk would be stuck servicing that one sector forever.